# Using jquery and css how do I create a delayed background color change animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a javascript-powered searchable html list. When the user types in some text that hones the list down to one result, I want the ".opaqueblock" div background to turn into a brighter color and then turn back to the original color after a quick delay. At the moment the color changes smoothly to a brighter when the user types in "Text 53" in the search box, but I can't figure out how to change the color back to the original darker color. I want a bright flash effect. Also, the each() function that I try to use to only change the background color of the isolated item "Text 53" is changing the background color of all the items. I do not want the color to change for list items that are hidden. Does anyone know a solution?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js""></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa' rel='stylesheet'>  <!--for search text-->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito' rel='stylesheet'>  <!--for search text-->

<script>


function ListSearch() {

  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue, resultsCount = 0, resultText = " results"; // Declare variables
  input = document.getElementById('myInput');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("DocumentList");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
  $('.opaqueBlock').css('border-color','transparent') //remove all borders in case a border was added when the results were honed down to 1

  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) { // Loop through all list items, hide those that don't match query
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
      resultsCount++;
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
  }

    if (resultsCount == 1) {
        $('.opaqueBlock').css('border-color','#68e8d5');
        $('.PreviewArrow').css("opacity", "1"); document.getElementById("results_span").style.color = "#b6fbd2"; 
        resultText = " result"; 

        $(".opaqueBlock:visible").each(
            $('.opaqueBlock').delay(300).css("background-color", "rgba(147,185,212,0.6)")
            /* $('.opaqueBlock').delay(300).css("background-color", "rgba(72,97,115,0.6)"); */
        );

        }   

    else if(resultsCount < 1){document.getElementById("results_span").style.color = "#fbb6bc";}
    else if(resultsCount < 3){document.getElementById("results_span").style.color = "#b6fbd2";}
    else if(resultsCount < 4){document.getElementById("results_span").style.color = "#b6d7fb";}
    else if(resultsCount < 5){document.getElementById("results_span").style.color = "#eeb8ff";}
    else {document.getElementById("results_span").style.color = "#fbb6bc";}

    document.getElementById("results_span").innerHTML = resultsCount + resultText;  

}

$(document).ready(function(){

    function HoverOverItem(thisParticularItem, DocImageLink){
        if (!thisParticularItem.hasClass("active_form_item") ) {
            $(".PreviewContainer").css("opacity", "0.3");
            $(".PreviewContainer").css("background-image", DocImageLink);
            $(".PreviewContainer").animate({'opacity': '1'},500);
            $("#ContentContainer").find('.active_form_item').removeClass('active_form_item');
            thisParticularItem.addClass("active_form_item");
        }   
    }
});

$(window).load(function(){
    $("#myInput").focus();  

    var ul, li, resultsCount = 0, resultText = " searchable documents"; // Declare variables
    ul = document.getElementById("DocumentList");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {resultsCount++;}   // Loop through all list items to get a count
    document.getElementById("results_span").innerHTML = resultsCount + resultText;  

});

</script>

<style>

#ContentContainer{
    height: 700px; 
    background-color: #132e54;
}
#ContentContainer a{text-decoration: none;}
#ContentContainer img{border: none;}


#search_prompt_div{margin-left: 16px;}
#search_prompt_div p{color: white; font-size: 14px; margin-bottom: 12px; font-family: comfortaa;}
#search_prompt_div input{height: 25px;font-size: 16px; width: 300px; font-family: comfortaa;}
#search_prompt_div #results_span{display: inline-block;margin-left: 6px; color: #fbb6bc; font-size: 12px;}

#DocumentListContainer{
    height: 600px;
    width: 660px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#DocumentList{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 6px 0 0 0;
    width: 105%;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 893px;
}

.opaqueBlock{
    opacity: 1; /*can set this to 0 if you want to animate it*/
    margin-left: 56px; /*can set this to 0 if you want to animate it*/
    display: inline-block;
    width: 490px; 
    height: 35px; 
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    background-color: rgba(72,97,115,0.6);
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .6s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .6s ease;
    -o-transition: all .6s ease;
}

.opaqueBlock:hover{
    border: 2px solid #5cb1d8;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";  
    opacity:0.7 !important;
}

.fileLinkContainer{ 
    width: 630px;
    height: 37px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.fileTextSpan{
    margin-left: 10px; 
    color: white; 
    margin-top: 5px; 
    font-family: 'Nunito' !important; 
    font-size: 19px !important;
    display: inline-block;
}

</style>

<div id="ContentContainer">

    <br><br><br>

    <div id="search_prompt_div">
        <p>Type something in the search box to find what you are looking for:</p>  
        <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..." onkeyup="ListSearch()">
        <span id="results_span"></span>
    </div>  

    <br/><br/><br/>

    <div class="PreviewContainer"></div>

    <div id="DocumentListContainer">
        <ul id="DocumentList">
            <li><div class="fileLinkContainer"><div class="opaqueBlock"><span class="fileTextSpan">Text 1</span></div></div></li>
            <li><div class="fileLinkContainer"><div class="opaqueBlock"><span class="fileTextSpan">Text 11</span></div></div></li>
            <li><div class="fileLinkContainer"><div class="opaqueBlock"><span class="fileTextSpan">Text 21</span></div></div></li>
            <li><div class="fileLinkContainer"><div class="opaqueBlock"><span class="fileTextSpan">Text 33</span></div></div></li>
            <li><div class="fileLinkContainer"><div class="opaqueBlock"><span class="fileTextSpan">Text 53</span></div></div></li>
        </ul>   
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. Please try and whittle that down to just the code needed to show the issue (a [mcve]). You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to provide a snippet on SO that runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about to use CSS keyframes somehow like this?

```
@keyframes anim {
0% { background-color: #fff; }
50%, 70% { background-color: #333; }
100% { background-color: #fff; }
}
```

Then just toggle class on the element by JS

Comment: thanks @DooM ! I your keyframes code and added this class  when I wanted to trigger it.

.flashingQuality{
  animation-name: anim;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 2;
}